# Category not loading template

Tags: templating, craft3, categories

I have created a new Category on a Craft 3 website but it will not load the template specified. Have other categories all working fine and can't get this one working at all.

Category Config below

[image]

I expect this to load my template `/pupil-of-the-month/index.html`

As per the below image in my templates folder.

[image]

But when I click on the category url - `http://local.domain.com/pupil-of-the-month/class/p1`

I get a not found error -

```
Template not found: pupil-of-the-month/class
```

Why is this Category not following the template specified in the admin settings?

Comment: I answered prematurely—I'm not sure how `class` is sneaking in at the end of the template it's looking for. 

Comment: Yep it’s really got me too. I had the exact same set up on a Craft 2 site so not sure what’s going on here.

Comment: Can you double-check the value stored in the database? I want to make sure you're seeing the right value in the CP. The `categorygroups_sites` table has a column named `template`, which should contain this value.

Comment: Yep Database looks good. urlFormat - `pupil-of-the-month/class/{slug}` template - `pupil-of-the-month/index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered what the issues was - it was my actual Category Names - the Class names which I had called, P1, P2, P3, P4 etc, which had a slug of p1, p2 etc.

Craft was picking those up as page numbers - and trying to route for that.

Discovered it when I had created an entry in a Structure with the title P1 which wasn't loading either.

Answer (score 1):

The template path specified in the admin should point to a single file, not a directory.

`index` files are only loaded when the Craft router falls all the way through element URIs and starts to look in your templates folder—in your case, that would be `local.domain.com/pupil-of-the-month`.

I suspect the confusion lies in that the router *does* eagerly look inside a directory for `index.*` templates in some narrow cases (as stated above), but that the pattern is not adopted by Category/Section/Tag settings.

See the official [Routing Docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/routing.html) for more information about the process Craft uses to resolve the template for a request.

Comment: The template path to the directory works for all my other Category Groups, just not sure what’s going on with this one. I added /index.html to the end but same error message